# Error while connecting to druid using SQL interface

Tags: druid, apache-calcite

I am trying to connect to druid database using avatica jar
Following is the code.

```
String url = "jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://localhost:8082/druid/v2/sql/avatica";
Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();

try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, connectionProperties))
{
    try (
            final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            final ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as rowcount FROM  wikiticker"))
    {
        while (resultSet.next())
        {
            int count = resultSet.getInt("rowcount");
            System.out.println("Total records:" + count);
        }
        resultSet.close();
    }
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get following exception , Can someone please let me know whats going wrong ? I have set the runtime property to enable sql.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute HTTP Request, got HTTP/404
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.AvaticaCommonsHttpClientImpl.send(AvaticaCommonsHttpClientImpl.java:138)
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.RemoteService.apply(RemoteService.java:34)
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.JsonService.apply(JsonService.java:172)
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Driver.connect(Driver.java:175)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at com.test.druid.sql.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your broker instance is missing `-Ddruid.sql.enabled=true` flag on startup. You can refer to http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/sql.html for further details.